# how can i get the full url including the http or https laravel

Tags: php, laravel

ive been looking around and cant find a solid answer.

Im trying to retrieve the full url including the https or http. reason why is because my development environment is a secured environment (c9.ide) so all style sheets point to a https cdn.

but when i deploy to production which isnt a https all my style sheets break because http is trying to load https stuff but its not a secure site, so i get error messages.

my goal is to achieve this in code

```
if(site_is_https) {
//load all of these files with proper url that points to https
} else {
//load all of these files with proper url that points to http
}
```

this is the only way i can think of solving this problem I'm having unless someone else knows a better solution. also how would i implement this in a mvc way instead of the logic in the header file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @JosephSilber's answer, another option would be to use a "protocol relative url".

Instead of
`http://example.com/my.css` or
`https://example.com/my.css`,

you would just use
`//example.com/my.css`.

By leaving off the specific protocol (keep the double slashes), the resource will be served over whichever protocol is currently being used. If you're on https, it'll be served over https. If you're on http, it'll be served over http.

Comment: Will this work if I'm calling my bootstrap and jquery files from a cdn link? I'm not on the computer atm

Comment: @helloworld Yeah. So, for example, if you wanted jquery from a CDN, your html would be `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Although, if your files are coming from a CDN that you know supports https, [google suggests just using https](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/): "We recommend that you load libraries from the CDN via HTTPS, even if your own website only uses HTTP. Nowadays, performance is fast, and caching works just the same. The CDN's files are served with CORS and Timing-Allow headers and allowed to be cached for 1 year."

Comment: everything looks good. 1 more question im using laravel `secure_asset()` on my paths how would i make it relative pathing like you're suggesting.

Comment: @helloworld Oh, in that case, just replace `secure_asset()` with `asset()`. It will automatically use the scheme (`http` vs `https`) of the current request.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question:

```
if (Request::isSecure()) {
    // ...
}
```

But you shouldn't need this. If you'd use the `url` helper, it will automatically use the proper scheme.

Comment: how can i find documentation on this?

Comment: It's not documented. Laravel uses Symfony, and `isSecure` is a method on Symfony's `request` class.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can use:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on') {//dothis}
```

Comment: Please don't use the globals directly like that. This goes against everything Symfony and Laravel are trying to accomplish. Also, this'll break the second you introduce a proxy into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be rational to include any "is it https:// or is it not?" logic in the code. Your code shouldn't worry how it's being served – that's a different layer completely.

1. Isn't it strange that your development environment is secure, but your production is not? A common practice would be to do it vice versa – you care about security on your production, not your staging server.
2. Use url() helper so that you don't need to think about URLs (what if you rename your site? http/https is not the only issue)
3. It's totally safe to include https:// links on http:// site – your browser won't complain at all. Browsers complain when insecure links are included on secure page. Therefore, feel free to include resources hosted on https:// pages using https:// at ALL times. Eg. a link to Google font, Facebook SDK or anything else – just use https:// no matter what to be safe.

Comment: well my browser is complaining about https on http (chrome)  and vice versa lol. and my site is not secure yet.

Comment: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://testlaravel2-bvcxtds.c9users.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet `

Comment: This is exactly what I said – the page is loaded using https:// but refers to some resources hosted on http://. So, resources referenced using https:// always work. Resources referenced using http:// may work or not work depending on schema of the main page

Comment: so how do i solve this issue, whenever i deploy i always have to change the links. thats why i wanna create this logic for the url